# How to Pause between actions in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In this example I'm using 1 button and web browser in VB using C#

I simply want to hit the button once then have it go to bing, wait 2 seconds, then go to google. Every method I've seen when I try it always has the pause or pauses at the beginning and not between navigation. Here's what I have. Thanks in advance.

```
public void  button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");


        Thread.sleep(2000);


        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

    }
```

Comment: What ultimate goal are you trying to achieve and why 2 seconds specifically? You could look into subscribing to the `DocumentCompleted` handler, once the bing page has finished loading then navigate to the google one?

Comment: The problem is that `Navigate` is asynchronous, so the delay is already over while the page is still loading. Assign a `DocumentCompleted` event handler, delay there and then navigate to Google.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't ran across documentscompleted. It was only 2 seconds to let it load fully. If you had a really quick example of using it in this situation that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @OmegaPoint It's simple enough to do but I'll add an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the [DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event and navigate to the second page there:

```
private void LoadPages()
{
     WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
     WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");
}

void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

    // Might want to dispose of the webbrowser instance or else
    // this event will fire again for the above call to `Navigate()`
    // and you'll end up in a loop.

    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();

    // Or you could unsubscribe to the event if you still need the browser instance
    WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to check which document has loaded in the DocumentCompletedEvent otherwise it will continually load the google page

Comment: Beat me to it - probably better to unsubscribe from the event rather than disposing of the webbrowser itself

Comment: This really helped me out so much. Thank you everyone!